# Heimdall has connectivity issues: Retrying again in 5 seconds to fetch data from Heimdall path=bor/span/1

Tags: polygon-pos

We are running a  Validator Node with  Bor v1.0.4 on and  Heimdall v1.0.1
We face these kind of logs often

Retrying again in 5 seconds to fetch data from Heimdall path=bor/span/1

What does this indicate and how to fix it?

We were under the assumption that this due to local network issue and had a check on our network connection.

But it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

These logs in Bor mean that it cannot connect to Heimdall.

The Heimdall doesn’t look in sync and hence it won’t have data on all the things that Bor would require.

So the recommended procedure would be to clear the historical data of both Heimdall and Bor and resync from the snapshot.

**Ensure the following is fine:**

Heimdall logs are normal or is it throwing up any errors?

Ensure Heimdall is fully synced by running: `curl localhost:26657/status`

Also ensure whether Heimdall is connected with the other peers.

```
curl localhost:26657/net_info? | jq .result.n_peers
```

If there aren’t any peers, check whether the seeds or persistent peers are rightly set on Heimdall and ensure Port 26656 is all open.

If that's not the case then try resetting Heimdall

```
sudo service heimdalld stop
heimdalld unsafe-reset-all
```

Sync Heimdall from Snapshot

```
wget -c <Snapshot URL>
tar -xzvf <snapshot file> -C <HEIMDALL_DATA_DIRECTORY>
```